# Did Mao Zedong have a person executed for saying his mangoes looked like a sweet potato?

Tags: history, china

This video entitled Mao's Miraculous Mangoes! is a bit satirical, but the one claim that somebody got executed during the cultural revolution for saying a mango looked like a sweet potato, is just ludicrous enough that I wonder if it really happened.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTyqoMUkbGk

Comment: @Avery: Google provides different results to different people, so referring someone to a Google (or lmgtfy) link may not show them the link you have in mind.  For me, that link gives a number of articles, only a few of which have any reference to the alleged "sweet potato" incident, and generally without giving any supporting evidence.

Comment: [This story on mentalfloss](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/57937/how-mao-accidentally-turned-mangoes-divine-objects-cultural-revolution) says the story appears in the writings of Alfreda Murck.  But she appears to be an art historian, and [the only published work of hers I found](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0674007824/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_taft_p1_i0) is on the art of the Song dynasty.  I wasn't able to check the text of this book; perhaps its account can be traced to primary sources, but it seems an unlikely place to start.

Comment: Oh, I see: the reference is to a 2013 exhibition catalog edited by Murck: [*Mao's Golden Mangos and the Cultural Revolution*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mao_s_Golden_Mangoes_and_the_Cultural_Re/mymWMQEACAAJ?hl=en).  There might be more info there, if someone was able to obtain a copy.

Comment: Sweet potato can also be a reference to the island of Taiwan due to its shape. That might make the people angrier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story seems plausible, except that this was a mob lynching, not anything ordered by Mao.

The story originates from Alfreda Murck, "[Golden Mangoes—The Life Cycle of a
Cultural Revolution Symbol](https://read.dukeupress.edu/archives-of-asian-art/article/57/1/1/97116/Golden-Mangoes-The-Life-Cycle-of-a-Cultural)" *Archives of Asian Art* (2007) 57 (1): 1–21.

> Getting a glimpse, the boy thought the fruit looked like a somewhat
> shriveled sweet potato. He went home crestfallen. The next morning he
> was awakened by pounding on the door; an uncle excitedly told his
> grandfather that Dr. Han had been arrested. Dr. Han was the much
> respected dentist in the community who had fitted the grandfather’s
> false teeth. Apparently, upon seeing the mango, Dr. Han remarked that
> is was nothing special and looked just like a sweet potato. His
> frankness was called blasphemy; he was arrested as a
> counterrevolutionary. He was soon tried and, to the dismay of the
> village, found guilty, paraded through the streets on the back of a
> truck as an example to the masses, taken to the edge of town, and
> executed with one shot to the head. His three sons were sent down to
> the countryside and his wife, reeling from the tragedy and bereft of
> family, soon died.

The citation for this story goes to:

> Wang Youqin, "Yayi Han Guangdi zhi si (The
> death of Dentist Han Guangdi)," web posting, 15 September 2005

However, this Wang Youqin is not a nobody. She is an expert in the history of the Cultural Revolution who [teaches at the University of Chicago](https://ceas.uchicago.edu/directory/youqin-wang). Here is the actual title of the blog post in hanzi:

> 王友琴《牙医韩光第之死》

I could not find where the original 2005 article was posted, but I did find that it was included in a [2004 publication](https://www.worldcat.org/title/wen-ge-shou-nan-zhe-guan-yu-po-hai-jian-jin-yu-sha-lu-de-xun-fang-shi-lu/oclc/646293290&referer=brief_results) in Hong Kong. This was also translated into [Japanese](https://www.worldcat.org/title/chugoku-bunka-daikakumei-junansha-den-to-bunkaku-dai-nenpyo-suko-naru-seiji-surogan-to-zankoku-hido-na-jittai-the-biographies-of-victims-and-a-chronological-table-of-the-proletarian-cultural-revolution-in-china-a-history-of-the-lofty-slogans-the-horrific-human-suffering-inflicted-and-their-disastrous-consequences/oclc/984986789&referer=brief_results).

The victim has an article on the Mainland Chinese encyclopedia [Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%9F%A9%E5%85%89%E7%AC%AC/13134254) which confirms that the CCP has no concern with this story, but it is unsourced. Additionally, this [Mainland Chinese article](https://www.chinatimes.com/cn/opinion/20200318000010-262107?chdtv) about the death appears in *China Times*, a national CCP news publication, and [this one](http://www.hybsl.cn/beijingcankao/beijingfenxi/2012-03-30/29178.html) appears in 同舟共进, the Guangdong branch publication of the CCP.